# How to assemble ARB assembly

Tags: linux, opengl, assembly, gpu

I just read this documentation : [this documentation](https://www.nvidia.com/docs/IO/8228/GDC2003_OGL_ARBVertexProgram.pdf)

I just scroll down then stop at Example Program #1 which have this code:

```
!!ARBvp1.0
ATTRIB pos = vertex.position;
PARAM mat[4] = { state.matrix.mvp };
# Transform by concatenation of the
# MODELVIEW and PROJECTION matrices.
DP4 result.position.x, mat[0], pos;
DP4 result.position.y, mat[1], pos;
DP4 result.position.z, mat[2], pos;
DP4 result.position.w, mat[3], pos;
# Pass the primary color through w/o lighting.
MOV result.color, vertex.color;
END
```

Then I just realized "Where to put this code?".
So I searched "How to assemble ARB assembly?" or "How to use ARB assembly?".absolutely I can't find anything
Finally I have question in here :

1. Which file extension is for ARB assembly?
2. How to assemble this code and make into executable file?

also I used Linux Mint 18.3 Cinnamon 64-bit

Comment: @zx485: yeah, the arb tag was completely wrongly used here, I removed it

Comment: Actually the *assembly* tag is not appropriate either, because this is not assembly, but a human readable intermediate representation (IR). As such it's much closer to SPIR-V, than GLSL.

Comment: "*I just read this documentation*" That document is from over *fifteen years ago*. Why would you be looking at it?

Comment: ARB assembly?  In $CURRENT_YEAR?!  What is this, Doom 3 retail? :)

Comment: Ah I love assembly language that's it...and I'm so confused that couldn't understand :(

Answer (score 8):

> 1. Which file extension is for ARB assembly?

There is none, use whatever you like.

> 2. How to assemble this code and make into executable file?

You don't.

The ARB "assembly" language is used for OpenGL shaders, which are not any executable files in the sense you seem to imply here. Those are for [shaders](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Shader) which are run on the GPU in context of the rendering pipeline, not indivual programs which can be executed directly.

Usually, you will need an OpenGL implementation supporting the [`GL_ARB_vertex_program`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/ARB/ARB_vertex_program.txt) or [`GL_ARB_fragment_program`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/ARB/ARB_fragment_program.txt) GL extensions (which never were part of any OpenGL core version), the driver will then create a binary for the particular GPU in use.

The ARB assembly shaders are completely outdated (at least from an end-user perspective, nvidia still uses its own extended dialects as an internal intermediate representation sometimes, but that doesn't really change the bigger picture), and have been replaced by the [OpenGL Shading Language (GLSL)](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Shading_Language) (which *is* part of core OpenGL since version 2.0 from 2004!).

Comment: Thanks for remove arb tag that refer to one program.also OpenGL implementation? it sound downloadable...Is it downloadable? (If I'm look like stupid I'm sorry)

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand your question? What do you want to download? The OpenGL implementation usually comes with your graphics drivers, or your Operating System.

Comment: I'm so sorry >< .then Do you know where can I find the example about compiling ARB code like compiling GLSL?

Comment: @user9241531 Most desktop GL implementations out there still do support these extensions. What else do you need?